# Is the function $f$ defined by $f(z)=z\cdot\Re(z)$ analytic at $z=0$?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Is $f(z)=z\cdot\Re(z)$ analytic at $z=0$?

I have tried this problem by satisfying Cauchy-Riemann equations. Then I found that f satisfies C-R equations at z=0 and first order partial derivatives are all continuous at z=0. So my question is that is it sufficient to say that f(z) is analytic at z=0.

Comment: For $f$ to be analytic at $0$, you would need $f$ to be representable as a convergent power series in some open neighborhood of $z = 0$. So, you actually need to check that the CR equations hold in a neighborhood of $0$ (and that the first order partials are also continuous in that neighborhood).

Comment: Analytic (as well as holomorphic) at a point doesn't exist, and when we say it we really mean "analytic on some open disk containing that point". 
Holomorphic on an open $U$ means complex-differentiable at every point of $U$.

Answer (score 1):

No, $f$ is not analytic at $0$ as mentioned in the comments by Stahal. To be analytic the function has to be differentiable around a neighbourhood of $0$. It is however differentiable at $0$ as @Lord Shark the Unknown has said.

Being differentiable at a point is a weaker condition that being analytic at a point as it has to be differentiable around an open neighbourhood around that point. Your question was probably set to emphasise those differences.

Also, you might want to know that if a function $f(z,\bar{z})$ is analytic at $0$, it is a function of $z$ only. (In other words, $f(z,\bar{z})=g(z)$ with no dependency on $\bar{z}$. But $Re(z)=\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}$ and your function is not analytic.)

Comment: The condition that $f(z,\bar z)=g(z)$ is not usable. Even $\bar z$ is a function of $z$...

Answer (score 0):

I would say that $f$ is differentiable at $0$ rather than analytic at $0$.
This is just a matter of proving that $\lim_{z\to0}f(z)/z=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that,one form of the Cauchy Riemann equations says that if $f$ is analytic then $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial\bar z}=0,$$ where $\frac\partial{\partial \bar z}=\frac 1 2 (\frac\partial{\partial x}+i\frac\partial{\partial y}\big)$.

> Could you see that the above equation does not hold in a neighbourhood  of zero?